# Apache Kafka Producer - Write to a Topic

Tags: apache-kafka

How could I write using a Kafka producer to a specific partition?

```
def publishMessage(tsDataPoints: Seq[DataPoint]): Future[Unit] = {
  Future {
    logger.info(s"Persisting ${tsDataPoints.length} data-points in Kafka topic ${producerConfig.topic}")
    val dataPoints = DataPoints("kafkaProducer", tsDataPoints)
    val jsonMessage = Json.toJson(dataPoints).toString()
    val recordMetaDataF = producer.send(
      new ProducerRecord[String, String](producerConfig.topic, jsonMessage)
    )
    // if we don't make it to Kafka within 3 seconds, we timeout
    val recordMetaData = recordMetaDataF.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    logger.info(
      s"persisted ${tsDataPoints.length} data-points to kafka topic:  " +
        s"${recordMetaData.topic()} partition: ${recordMetaData.partition()} offset: ${recordMetaData.offset()}"
    )
    ()
  }
}
```

The code above writes to the default partition which is partition 0, as I do not have my topic partitioned yet!

How could I read using a consumer from a specific partition? Here is what I have for my consumer:

```
  def readFromKafka = {
    val consumerRecords =
      consumer.poll(kafkaConsumerPollTimeOut.toMillis).iterator().asScala.toSeq
    toTsDataPointSeq(consumerRecords).flatten
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the contructors for the `ProducerRecord` is the following

```
ProducerRecord(String topic, Integer partition, K key, V value)
```

So if you specify the partition (and the partition exist) you record will go there.

If you want a consumer to consume for a specific partition, you need to call this method `consumer.assign(List<TopicPartition> partitions)` there you can specify which is the topic and partition that you want.

Comment: What is the k key doing in the constructor? How do I compute the key?

Comment: "If a valid partition number is specified that partition will be used when sending the record. If no partition is specified but a key is present a partition will be chosen using a hash of the key. If neither key nor partition is  present a partition will be assigned in a round-robin fashion."


So basically the key can be present or not, if its present it will be use by kafka to distribute the information among the partitions ( Records with the same key will always go to the same partition)

Comment: In the constructor above, I have to provide both the Key and the Partition, so how does your statement "So basically the key can be present.... ". The key is not an Option. I will take a look into the API to see if there is a constructor that takes in only a partition instead of a Key

Comment: is an option, pass null

Comment: read what the documentation is saying "If neither key nor partition is present a partition will be assigned in a round-robin fashion"

Comment: Ok I will read the documentation! I have yet another question. What do you think might be the best way to model 2 topics where I have one topic for read signals and the other topic for write signals? I then have one consumer that consumes from both these topics and dumps the values into a OpenTSDB database. Is this a viable approach?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely do something like that, a consumer can be subscribed to multiple topics, so it will get messages from both in your case